# Restoring View values onResume for a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 9 fragments that I switch between using tab navigation in my activity. In each of these fragment's onPause method, I save all EditText, Spinner and CheckBox values to my database. Then on each of these fragment's onResume method, I retrieve these values from the database and fill the EditTexts, Spinners and CheckBoxes with their values. I've checked the values in the onPause and onResume methods, and they are being correctly stored and retrieved. I'm not sure why the UI state isn't being instantiated correctly. The EditTexts and Spinners load properly, but the Checkboxes will sometimes be unchecked when I change between the fragments. Am I missing something particular to fragments, because this method works on all of my other activities? As far as I know, the onResume method is the last one to be called when the fragment gets opened again.

In onPause I retrieve the object from the database and call the saveValuesToDB function.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Get the structure from the DB corresponding to the values in the Shared Preferences
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preferences_filename), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final String project_name = sharedPref.getString("project_name","");
    final String structure_topo_number = sharedPref.getString("structure_topo_number","");

    returned_structure = null;

    try {
        Thread getStructure = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                returned_structure = structureDB.structureDAO().getStructure(structure_topo_number,project_name);
            }
        });

        getStructure.start();
        getStructure.join();
    } catch(Exception e){
        returned_structure = null;
    }

    // Structure already exists in DB. Set its values equal to the current inputted values
    if(returned_structure != null){
        saveValuesToDB(returned_structure);
    }
}
```

Then in saveValuesToDB, I set the object's values.

```
/* Save all currently entered values to the Database */
//region
public void saveValuesToDB(Structure structure){

    structure_being_saved = structure;

    // Measure Down Type
    structure_being_saved.pipe_measure_down_types.set(5,pipe6_measure_down_type_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    // Measure Down
    structure_being_saved.pipe_measure_downs.set(5,pipe6_measure_down_edit_text.getText().toString());

    // Measure Down Angle
    structure_being_saved.pipe_measure_down_angles.set(5,pipe6_measure_down_angle_edit_text.getText().toString());

    // Pipe Material
    structure_being_saved.pipe_materials.set(5,pipe6_material_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

And in onResume I load the object again and call the setValuesFromDB function

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Get the structure from the DB corresponding to the values in the Shared Preferences
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preferences_filename), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final String project_name = sharedPref.getString("project_name","");
    final String structure_topo_number = sharedPref.getString("structure_topo_number","");

    returned_structure = null;

    try {
        Thread getStructure = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                returned_structure = structureDB.structureDAO().getStructure(structure_topo_number,project_name);
            }
        });

        getStructure.start();
        getStructure.join();
    } catch(Exception e){
        returned_structure = null;
    }

    if(returned_structure != null){
        setValuesFromDB(returned_structure);
    }

    latitude = 0.0;
    longitude = 0.0;
}
//endregion

private void setValuesFromDB(Structure structure) {

    current_structure = structure;

    /* For all of the spinners, check if the position of the item from the DB is not null */
    // Measure Down Type
    if (pipe6_measure_down_type_spinner_adapter.getPosition(current_structure.pipe_measure_down_types.get(5)) != -1) {
        pipe6_measure_down_type_spinner.setSelection(pipe6_measure_down_type_spinner_adapter.getPosition(current_structure.pipe_measure_down_types.get(5)));
    } else {
        pipe6_measure_down_type_spinner.setSelection(0);
    }

    // Measure Down
    pipe6_measure_down_edit_text.setText(current_structure.pipe_measure_downs.get(5));
    pipe6_measure_down_edit_text.setSelection(pipe6_measure_down_edit_text.getText().length());

    // Measure Down Angle
    // If the value from the DB is blank, default it to 90
    if (current_structure.pipe_measure_down_angles.get(5).equals("")) {
        pipe6_measure_down_angle_edit_text.setText("90");
    } else {
        pipe6_measure_down_angle_edit_text.setText(current_structure.pipe_measure_down_angles.get(5));
    }
    pipe6_measure_down_angle_edit_text.setSelection(pipe6_measure_down_angle_edit_text.getText().length());

    // Pipe Material
    if (pipe6_material_spinner_adapter.getPosition(current_structure.pipe_materials.get(5)) != -1) {
        pipe6_material_spinner.setSelection(pipe6_material_spinner_adapter.getPosition(current_structure.pipe_materials.get(5)));
    } else {
        pipe6_material_spinner.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add code.

Comment: Are you initializing in oncreateview or onviewcreated? Also in your xml do you have any isChecked properties set.

Comment: I initialize them in onResume